# Flags UPDATE optimization for MVCC

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.6, mvcc, postgresql-performance

We have a table with 200k rows where we change some flags multiple times per day. 
If i have understood correctly an UPDATE on postgres is a DELETE+INSERT on disk.

I'm wondering if this is highly inefficient for our use case. What if each tuple has a big size? Are the entire tuples written again?

I was thinking to move those status flags on a separate table so that we rewrite only small tuples reducing useless i/o. Is this a correct approach or i'm on the wrong track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki):</sub>*

You're basically right.

It will also help if you define your separate tables with a certain amount of *free space* (see [`fillfactor`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-STORAGE-PARAMETERS)) so that PostgreSQL can perform *Heap-only tuples* updates.

See [Increase the speed of UPDATE query using HOT UPDATE (Heap only tuple)](https://www.dbrnd.com/2016/12/postgresql-increase-the-speed-of-update-query-using-hot-update-heap-only-tuple-mvcc-fill-factor-vacuum-fragmentation/) by Anvesh Patel.